# How to enter a series of numbers in middle (not at the end) automatically in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to generate series of numbers in the fields using fill series . the number is in the middle not at the end ... please some one help me out

Comment: This question would be much better if you provided some sample data together with the expected results. Parsing text is subject to a myriad of conditions and attempting a solution blindly would be fruitless.

Answer (score 1):

A formula such as:

```
="ABC"&TEXT(ROW(),"000")&"xyz"
```

demonstrates one approach.

This [concatenates](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d) with `&` two static string components (`ABC` and `xyz`) around a variable determined by [ROW](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/ROW-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d) which has been formatted with [TEXT](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Text-Function.html).

Comment: I had been thinking along the lines of `=REPLACE("ABCxyz", 4, 0, TEXT(ROW(), "000"))`. Seems no one ever uses the [REPLACE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/REPLACE-REPLACEB-functions-3a666e1d-153c-4c3f-8aa8-0abedd2c6ee7) anymore.